# bash code to count A to z char with count string input string and give output in new string

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, logic, bash-completion

Hi folks just started write code in bash but stuck in my own question in want to count a to alphabets repetation in string like

```
read -p 'enter the string' str # SUPPOSE STRING USER ENTER IS
```

input =                  `AAASSSSFFRREEE`

i wanna get output like= `A3S4F2R2E3`

what can i do i am trying with for condition and  this program is making monkey out of me

Comment: Could you have a second or more repetition of the same char ? Input string like that :  AAASSSSFFRREEEAAAFFFFFEE, if it's possible, what is the desired output?

Comment: please update the question with your code attempt(s) and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: how to treat a mix of upper and lower case? if the input is `Aa` should the output be `A2` or `A1a1`?

Comment: Just no case sensitive aaaAA = A5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `grep -o, --only-matching`

  Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
  with each such part on a separate output line.
  Using `.` as pattern for every character

---

```
grep -o . <<<"AASS"
A
A
S
S
```

---

- `uniq -c, --count`

  prefix lines by the number of occurrences

---

```
grep -o . <<<"AASS"|uniq -c
      2 A
      2 S
```

---

- `awk '{printf "%s%d", $2,$1}'`

  Reorder the output. Character '$2' first then number '$1'.
  Print all in a single line

---

```
grep -o . <<<"AASS"|uniq -c|awk '{printf "%s%d", $2,$1}END{print ""}'
A2S2
```

**Unsorted alphabet**

```
$ string="AAASSSSFFRREEE" 
$ grep -o . <<<"$string"|uniq -c|awk '{printf "%s%d", $2,$1}END{print ""}'
A3S4F2R2E3
$ string="AAASSSSFFRREEEAAAAFFFFFEE"
A3S4F2R2E3A4F5E2
```

**Sorted alphabet**

```
$ string="AAASSSSFFRREEE" 
$ grep -o . <<<"$string"|sort|uniq -c|awk '{printf "%s%d", $2,$1}END{print ""}'
A3E3F2R2S4
$ string="AAASSSSFFRREEEAAAAFFFFFEE"
A7E5F7R2S4
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to loop over the string and strip away the first characters while counting them.

Example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS='' read -rp 'enter the string: ' str

res=''
# loop while the string is not empty
while [[ -n $str ]]
do
    # get the first character
    ch=${str:0:1}
    # create a regex matching the start of the string,
    # on one or more of the first character
    regex="^($ch+)"
    # perform the regex matching
    [[ "$str" =~ $regex ]]
    # the matching string
    match="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    # concatenate the character + the count to the result
    res="$res$ch${#match}"
    # remove the matching characters from the string
    str=${str#"$match"}
done

# print the result
printf "%s\n" "$res"
```

Examples:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `AAASSSSFFRREEE` | `A3S4F2R2E3` |
| `AAASSSSFFRREEEAAAFFFFFEE` | `A3S4F2R2E3A3F5E2` |

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    $0 = toupper($0)
    while ( char = substr($0,1,1) ) {
        printf "%s%d", char, gsub(char,"")
    }
    print ""
}
```

```
$ echo 'AAASSSSFFRREEE' | awk -f tst.awk
A3S4F2R2E3
```

The above assumes that the input doesn't contain any regexp metachars (you said it's to work on letters so that's fine) and you want the following output if the letters aren't all contiguous (you didn't answer [@ArnaudValmary's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72583652/bash-code-to-count-a-to-z-char-with-count-string-input-string-and-give-output-in/72604279#comment128216512_72583652) about that):

```
$ echo 'AAASSSSFFRREEEAAAFFFFFEE' | awk -f tst.awk
A6S4F7R2E5
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an `awk`-based solution that takes any unsorted input, and generates sorted output :

```
 echo 'ZZZCGGGGAAASSSWSFXXXRRRYYYUUUUYYFRREEEAAAAJBBBQQQAAQQQBFFFBFFPPEE' |

{m,n,g}awk '{
   
26      for(_= ( ___=(_^=_+=_^=_<_)^--_) + \
            _^((____="")*(___+=_^_)); _<___; _++) {

26         __ = sprintf("%c",_)             # if you`re not using nawk, then
                                            # combine this with sub() below
26         sub("$", (__) gsub(__,""), ____)
        }
 1      gsub("[A-Z]0","", ____)
 1      print ____
    }'


A9B5C1E5F7G4J1P2Q6R5S4U4W1X3Y5Z3
```

Comment: @babybash : and yet my solution is the only one (so far) not requiring a sorting utility or multi-pass of the same input data